# Want ideas on how to reduce number of SELECTs to increase performance

Tags: sql-server, count

I am stuck at one query. Actually I want to reduce the number of select I am using. I want to count the number of rows for each scenario.

The description of column of tables are-

Here `month` is month of year

`Name` is name of Person

Attention Required is whether any attention is required to them. Here we have conditions-

If attention required is 'N' and isdate(Date)=0 then it comes `No Attention required.`
If attention required is 'N' and isdate(Date)=1 then it comes `Attention Completed`
If attention required is 'Y' (then don't need to consider Date column) it comes in `Attention Required`

Date is simply a date when they require medical attention it can be null or any date

Outsider- IF '0' then it is from the country else it is foreigner. For outsider also, same rules are applied for Attention Required. Just the flag will distinguish between insider and outsider.

Here is the sample table

```
    Month         Name           Attention Required Y/N    Date       Outsider
  January          A                  N                 2015-01-02     0
  January          B                  N                   Null         0
  January          C                  Y                   Null         0
  January          D                  Y                 2015-01-20     1
  February         E                  Y                 2015-02-01     1
  February         F                  N                   null         0
  February         G                  Y                   null         0
  February         H                  N                 2015-02-21     1
  February         I                  N                   null         0
  March            J                  Y                   null         1
  March            K                  N                 2015-03-08     1
  March            L                  N                   null         0
  March            M                  Y                   null         1
  March            N                  N                   null         1
  April            O                  N                 2014-04-04     1
  April            P                  Y                   null         0
  April            Q                  N                2015-04-10      0
  April            R                  Y                 null           0
  April            S                  Y                 null           1
```

I want the output in this format-

```
Month                 Insider                                                    Insider Total              Outsider                                                    Outsider Total       Grand Total
         No Attention Required    Attention Completed       Attention Required                    No Attention Required    Attention Completed       Attention Required 
January        1                         1                          1                   3              0                       0                            1                  2                4
February       2                         0                           1                  3              0                       0                            1                  2                5
March          1                         0                           0                  1              1                       1                            2                  4                5
April          0                         1                           2                  3              0                       1                            1                  2                5  
Grand Total    4                         2                           4                 10              1                       3                            5                  9               19
```

So I am not able to reduce the no of select. For each column I cannot use a different select query. I am using these query to find the count by month.

```
For insiders-


select Month, count(Name) as No_Attention_Required
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='N' and isdate(Date)=0
     and Outsider='0' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Attention_Completed
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='N' and isdate(Date)=1
     and Outsider='0' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Attention_Required
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='Y' 
     and Outsider='0' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Insider_Total
FROM sample where Outsider='0' group by Month




For Outsiders-


select Month, count(Name) as No_Attention_Required
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='N' and isdate(Date)=0
     and Outsider='1' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Attention_Completed
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='N' and isdate(Date)=1
     and Outsider='1' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Attention_Required
FROM sample where Attention_Required ='Y' 
     and Outsider='1' group by Month

select Month, count(Name) as Outsider_Total
FROM sample where Outsider='1' group by Month
```

And after that I planned to join them by month.

I need in help reducing the number of select to have this count. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
EDITED:
```

Here I is my sample case statement

```
 select  Month,case when Attention_Required='N' and isdate(Date)=0 then count(Name) end as Attention_Not_Needed,
           case when Attention_Required='N' and isdate(Date)=1 then count(Name) end as Attention_Completed
     FROM sample where  Attention_Required='N'
     and Outsider='0' group by Month,Attention_Required,Date
```

Comment: Is the grand total necessary? You don't have it in your sample SQL and it complicates the query somewhat.

Comment: On a side note, your title is backwards - you want to improve the performance, not make it perform worse!

Comment: Yeah Grand total  is necessary... I forgot to include that also.

Comment: Just use a `CASE WHEN.. THEN.. ` so you hit the table once

Comment: Yeah I tried but it than I have include that column in Group By Clause and then it won't work

Comment: what column?   it should have worked.  Please post your attempt using `CASE WHEN` so that we can debug it.

Comment: Update the question for case statement

Comment: `SUM(case when Attention_Required='N' and isdate(Date)=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Attention_Not_Needed` and so on.Your syntax was off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to get the numbers in one go, as well as use `ROLLUP` to get the summaries;

```
SELECT 
  Month, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'N' AND ISDATE(date) = 0 AND outsider = 0 THEN 1 END) AS I_NAR,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'N' AND ISDATE(date) = 1 AND outsider = 0 THEN 1 END) AS I_AC,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'Y'                      AND outsider = 0 THEN 1 END) AS I_AR,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN                                                   outsider = 0 THEN 1 END) AS I_TOTAL,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'N' AND ISDATE(date) = 0 AND outsider = 1 THEN 1 END) AS O_NAR,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'N' AND ISDATE(date) = 1 AND outsider = 1 THEN 1 END) AS O_AC,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Attention_Required = 'Y'                      AND outsider = 1 THEN 1 END) AS O_AR,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN                                                   outsider = 0 THEN 1 END) AS O_TOTAL,
  COUNT(1) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM sample
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Month)
```

...which gives the result;

```
Month    I_NAR       I_AC        I_AR        I_TOTAL     O_NAR       O_AC        O_AR        O_TOTAL     GRAND_TOTAL
-------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
January  1           1           1           3           0           0           1           3           4
February 2           0           1           3           0           1           1           3           5
March    1           0           0           1           1           1           2           1           5
April    0           1           2           3           0           1           1           3           5
NULL     4           2           4           10          1           3           5           10          19
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the CASE statement correctly.   Here is how you should have used it:

```
select Month,
 SUM(case when Attention_Required='N' and isdate(Date)=0 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Attention_Not_Needed
, SUM(case when Attention_Required='N' and isdate(Date)=1 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Attention_Completed 
FROM sample 
where Outsider='0' 
group by Month
```